# Как сверстать такой хаб?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Есть грид в несколько строк из одинаковых блоков. По клику в каждый блок после текущей строки должен открываться хаб, отодвигая следующие строки грида, со стрелкой, указывающей на блок, в который кликнули. Как в iTunes.

Как такое сверстать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл добавить, что всё это лежит в резиновом контейнере: блоков в строке может быть и три и сколько угодно

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/jLgzhenj/

Comment: elijah-cdr, лучше бы вам перенести свое добавление из комментария непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Верстать на `radio` как по ссылке в комментарии под вопросом - неправильно с точки зрения семантики. Да, такие костыли используются на в примерах типа "how to make it only via css" и даже, вроде как, работают. Но так делать не нужно, если вы не хотите выпендриться своим знанием CSS, а хотите получить действительно рабочий экземпляр без костылей.

Вот как следует поступить в вашем случае:
 1. Делаем сетку из квадратиков.
 2. Каждому квадратику добавляет дочерний элемент (блок, который будет "выпадать")
 3. JavaScript'ом ловим клик по квадратику
 4. При клике добавляем дочернему элементу класс "show"
 5. Определяем стиль для класса `.show` следующим образом:
     Сначала добавляем `visibility: visible;`
     После этого увеличиваем высоту элемента до нужной
     Потом меняем цвет текста на нужный (сначала он был равен фону, чтобы его не было видно)

При клике на другой элемент убираем `.show` в текущего элемента и добавляем кликнутому (если этого требует задача).

Сейчас реализую что-то подобное, и, если сами не сможете сверстать по моему алгоритму, добавлю код.

### UPD

Пока что мое решение такое: http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/gMwzKa.
Минусы: tip не занимает всю ширину родительского блока. Это лечится добавлением `position: absolute;`, но при таком решении следующий ряд блоков не смещается вниз. Как вариант, можно устанавливать родителю (`.container`) класс `.show`, который будет добавлять ему `padding`, равный высоте появляющегося .tip'а. Но писать это - это уже работа. А любая работа должна оплачиваться. Так что, как минимум, на мысль я вас, думаю, навел.

Comment: А, ну и еще, конечно, стоит при каждом новом выполнении ф-ции `openTip()` убирать `.show` с остальных блоков, чтобы всегда был виден только один .tip.

Comment: И еще, насчет треугольничка сверху. JavaScript'ом получаем центр блока, на который нажали, а затем устанавливаем ::before .tip'а (как раз этот треугольник) слева на столько пикселей, сколько получили JavaScript'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так. Данные в блок можно загружать аяксом (но это ты уж сам как-нибудь).

Единственное НО - рассчёт позиции треугольника какой-то костыльный. Наверняка это можно и лучше сделать. Но что имеем, то имеем.

```js
"use strict";

var notification_status = new Array;
var row_elems = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap > .row > div");
var current_tab = undefined;

// Считает позицию элемента
function elemPosition(a_this, items_count) {
  var block_position = 0;
  var cur = a_this.previousElementSibling;

  for (var i = 0; i < items_count; i++) {
    if (cur) {
      cur = cur.previousElementSibling;
      block_position += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return block_position;
}

// Удаляет созданное окно, если оно было создано.
function removeNotification() {
  if (document.querySelector(".notification") != null) {
    var elem = document.querySelector(".notification");
    elem.remove();
  }
}

// Создание информационного окна
function addNotification(a_this) {
  var wrap = a_this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var notification = document.createElement("div");
  notification.className = "notification";
  var triangle = document.createElement("div");
  triangle.className = "triangle";

  var items_count = a_this.parentNode.children.length
  var item = elemPosition(a_this, items_count);

  var triangle_position_left = (50 / items_count) - (10 / items_count) + ((50 / items_count) * item * 2);

  triangle.style.marginLeft = triangle_position_left + "%";

  wrap.appendChild(notification);
  notification.appendChild(triangle);
}

// Навешиваение обработчиков на нужные элементы
row_elems.forEach(function(item, i, row_elems) {

  row_elems[i].onclick = function() {
    if (i == current_tab) {
      removeNotification();
      current_tab = undefined;
    } else {
      removeNotification();
      addNotification(this);
      current_tab = i;
    }
  };

});
```

```css
input:focus,
button:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:active,
button:active,
textarea:active {
  outline: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
div.row > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96, 0.7);
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div.row > div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
div.row > div:not(:hover) {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.notification {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.7);
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.triangle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -19px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
.triangle:after {
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас статичная страница и не так уж много этих строк, то можно заранее сверстать "хаб", задать его высоту как `0px` и нужный `transition`, а по клику увеличивать высоту "хаба" до нужной.